# WireGuard stops listening on my public IP once I change gateway

Tags: debian, networking, vpn, wireguard

I have a TurnKeyLinux (Debian) WireGuard vm set up.

Let's say the WAN address is 1.2.3.4, my WireGuard VM is 192.168.0.10 and the gateway is set to my cablemodem 192.168.0.1

Ports are open as required for the WireGuard all with no problems, I can connect to 1.2.3.4 from my cellphone even when I'm not at home, it all works great.

However, as soon as I change the gateway to 192.168.0.100, which I have set up as a secondary gateway on my home network already working fine for other tasks, it no longer is listening on 1.2.3.4 and I can't even handshake with the server.

Why?

How do I troubleshoot this?

I want the server to be using the 192.168.0.100 gateway but still be listening for connections on 192.168.0.10, it's IP address.

Thank you

Comment: I think you may need to show a network diagram